# C# SQLite Parameterized Select Using LIKE

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to do an SQL query such as

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE hostname LIKE '%myhostname%';
```

This works fine in plain SQL, but when I use System.Data.SQLite in C#, it only works with a literal, not a parameter, such as

```
string sel = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE hostname LIKE '%@host%'";
...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@host", "myhostname");
```

This returns no results.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't do that. The parameters must be complete values - it's not just a string substitution into the SQL. You could do this instead:

```
string sel = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE hostname LIKE @host";
...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@host", "%myhostname%");
```

Comment: `string sel = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE] where hostname like '%'+@host+'%'";` would also work.

Comment: Thanks Mark - this helped a ton.  Donnie - I tried this earlier and it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: just encountered the same situation in Ruby with Sqlite3, and your solution worked like a champ there too.  Upvote, which was for some reason met with a kick-line of ponies on my screen? :/

Comment: @Donnie, your statement works, but I had to use concatenation with `||` instead of `+`

Comment: It Worked. Cool. :)

Answer (score 17):

Easiest way to do this is to use '||'

**Use :**

```
const string qry = "SELECT SiteNum FROM WorkTable WHERE WTName LIKE @wtName || '%' ";
```

**Instead Of:**

```
const string qry = "SELECT SiteNum FROM WorkTable WHERE WTName LIKE @wtName%";
```

I have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32297491/2454277)

Comment: Thanks for this! I was looking for a way to do it workout having to put the "%" characters into the search parameter value. I see that @Thunderforge commented on the accepted answer basically saying what you've said here, but I wouldn't have noticed that without seeing your answer first.