# How can I use the Like Operator with a Parameter in a SQLite query?

Tags: c#, sqlite, prepared-statement, sql-injection, sql-like

I can get the result I expect by entering this in LINQPad:

```
SELECT * FROM WorkTable WHERE WTName LIKE "DSD__20090410014953000%"
```

(it shows me the record which has a WTName value of DSD__20090410014953000.xml")

But trying to do this programmatically is proving trying. I tried:

```
const string qry = "SELECT SiteNum FROM WorkTable WHERE WTName LIKE @wtName%";
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(HHSUtils.GetDBConnection()))
{
    con.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("wtName", tableName));
    siteNum = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

...but it causes the app to crash, and my log file tells me why:

```
Message: From application-wide exception handler: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database
near "%": syntax error
```

So maybe it thinks the query parameter is named "wtName%" instead of "wtName"; but separating the parameter and the "whatever" opertor ("%") with a space doesn't work, either.

I could go retro/kludgy by just embedding the query parameter into the string like so:

```
const string qry = String.Format("SELECT SiteNum FROM WorkTable WHERE WTName LIKE {0}%", tableName);
```

...and doing without the query parameter altogether, but I'm afraid if I did that [Troy Hunt](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) would show up at my house and flail me with a bedrail while railing about SQL Injection.

How can I get my data and simultaneously write safe code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The wildcard `%` should be added to the parameter value, not to the parameter name

```
const string qry = "SELECT SiteNum FROM WorkTable WHERE WTName LIKE @wtName";
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(HHSUtils.GetDBConnection()))
{
    con.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@wtName", tableName + "%"));
    siteNum = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

And, I am not sure if it matters here, but, usually, I insert the parameter name with the exact name used in the placeholder ( @wtName )

Answer (score 9):

Easiest way to do this is to use '||'

**Use :**

```
const string qry = "SELECT SiteNum FROM WorkTable WHERE WTName LIKE @wtName || '%' ";
```

**Instead Of:**

```
const string qry = "SELECT SiteNum FROM WorkTable WHERE WTName LIKE @wtName%";
```

Comment: Why do one and not the other?

Answer (score -2):

Try defining query like this:

```
const string qry = "SELECT SiteNum FROM WorkTable WHERE WTName LIKE @wtName + '%'";
```

Comment: Didn't try on SQLite but it works on SQL Server for sure. I copied it from existing project.

Comment: The concatenation operator for strings in SQLite is  || so you should write `@wtName || '%'` Still I believe that this is too error prone and not portable

Comment: @Dragon your answer is valid for SQL Server but not for SQLite , As I have answred in SQLite you must use '||' instead of  '+'