# SQLite C++ statement format

Tags: c++, sqlite, bind

I am using SQLite in C++ to query a database. I want to use the `LIKE` operator in a select statement such as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName LIKE '%abc%'
```

But I need to bind the value of abc in the above statement to query. Usually, for normal statements such as `SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName=@name`, we can use `query.bind(@name, 'name');`

But for the `LIKE` operator, I am not able to get this working. I am not sure if I should be giving it as `'%@name%'`? This doesn't work and throws an binding error exception.

Any suggestions will be really helpful since otherwise, I need to go through the whole search result having 100's of rows and check each row for a value from an big string array. The idea is to give the string array element as the binding value for the `LIKE` operator to search the database and fetch just one row.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot, in advance.

Esash

Comment: Binding only works with parameter values, not other parts of the statement. You will have to construct the LIKE clause using string manipulation, or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329953/c-sharp-sqlite-parameterized-select-using-like.

Comment: Have you tried `LIKE @name` and `query.bind("@name", "%" + abc + "%")`  [subject to fixing my syntax] ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the percent signs after binding:

```sql
... WHERE Col Like '%' || ? || '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If name is a variable, use this:

```
name = "%" + name + "%";
query.bind("@name", name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm.