# Xamarin forms 4.x searchbar crashes when text changes

Tags: c#, sqlite

Summary: The program allows the user to have a list of players. I have it so that the user can add players to the SQLite database and modify or delete them. I am trying to create a Match between players, the idea being that the user will use the SearchBar to find the name and select it from the quick list as they type. I've been searching around for ways to use the SearchBar and how to access specific data from the SQLite database and I think I have it generating a list of Players to choose from. But when I run the program and attempt to search for a name, it crashes on the first letter and Visual Studio reports an error: SQLite.SQLiteException: 'no such column: a' (where 'a' is the first letter that I typed). In the background is the message: Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

Here is how I have it set up. Here is the search bar on MatchEntryPage.xmal

```
                    <StackLayout>
                        <SearchBar Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                   Placeholder="Player 1"
                                   TextChanged="OnPlayer1SearchTextChanged"
                                   x:Name="Player1SearchBar" />
                        <ListView x:Name="Player1SearchList"
                                  Footer="" />
                    </StackLayout>
```

Here is how I handle the text change in MatchEntryPage.xmal.cs

```
async void OnPlayer1SearchTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player1SearchList.ItemsSource = await 
            App.Database.GetPlayersByNameAsync(Player1SearchBar.Text);
    }
```

In the player class definition PlayerDatabase.cs here is the function:

```
    public async Task<List<Player>>GetPlayersByNameAsync(string name)
    {
        List<Player> result = await _database.QueryAsync<Player>("SELECT * from Player where 
             PlayerName LIKE " + name);
        return result;
    }
```

Additional notes: Some of the reading I did mentioned that best practice is to not use SQL directly but I am unsure how to do this. Also, here are other functions in PlayerDatabase.cs that I am able to use to populate a ListView to show the full list of players in the database

```
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

    public PlayerDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
        _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _database.CreateTableAsync<Player>().Wait();
    }

    public Task<List<Player>> GetPlayersAsync()
    {
        return _database.Table<Player>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<Player> GetPlayerAsync(int id)
    {
        return _database.Table<Player>()
            .Where(i => i.ID == id)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
 public async Task<List<Player>>GetPlayersByNameAsync(string name)
    {
        List<Player> result = await _database.QueryAsync<Player>("SELECT * from Player where 
             PlayerName LIKE " + name);
        return result;
    }
```

to

```
 public async Task<List<Player>>GetPlayersByNameAsync(string name)
    {
        List<Player> result = await _database.QueryAsync<Player>("SELECT * from Player where 
             PlayerName LIKE '%" + name+ "%');
        return result;
    }
```

But you should use SqlParameter instead of variables directly. To get better performance and avoid sql-injection - read here: [C# SQLite Parameterized Select Using LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329953/c-sharp-sqlite-parameterized-select-using-like/32297560)

---

I am not use to SqlLite, but it might be possible to write:

```
    public Task<IEnumerable<Player>> GetPlayerWithNamesOfAsync(string wildcardName)
    {
        return _database.Table<Player>()
            .Where(p => p.PlayerName.Contains(wildcardName))
            .ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! The correction to my SQL query worked, and I adjusted the ListView to include a data template that shows the name. I tried the parameter based function but got the following error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActvFoosball.Models.Player[]' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ActvFoosball.Models.Player>>'. I'll try to read up and see if I can find out why (unless someone wants to add that in!) otherwise I'll include a new question.

Comment: The best would be to use my second answer solution (`GetPlayerWithNamesOfAsync`), but else create a new SO issue and we will help you through.